# Multiselect template with condition?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, multi-select

Hello i am use kendo UI and in multiselect have some problems with templte, this my current template

```
k-item-template= '"#: codeNameId # - #: (+sumVat) # dol. nal; #: sumNameId # dol. without nal"'
```

but i am want template with condition where if (codeNameId === 999) {
'"#: codeNameId # - #: (+sumVat) # dol. nal; #: sumNameId # dol. without nal"'} else  {'"nal; #: sumNameId # nal"'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template is wrong. You're missing additional opening hash symbols on the outer and inner if statement.

Please see below for working example.

```
#if (codeNameId === 999) {# #: codeNameId # - #: (+sumVat) # dol. nal #: sumNameId # dol. without nal #} else {# nal; #: sumNameId # nal #}#
```